# Problem in program to count number of words, sentences and letters in C

Tags: c, cs50

I needed to make a program to count the number of words, sentences and letters by getting an input from the user. The program works perfectly until the input i give is multi-lined. If the input is longer than the text that can fit in the terminal window, the program starts to ignore all full stops/question marks/exclamation marks. I don't know why, and I'd like some help. This doesn't happen if the text can fit in one line of the terminal window. I also printed every character when it's read by the program, but that also ignores all full stops/question marks/ exclamation marks. None of those characters get printed. For clarification, a sentence is just the number of full stops/question marks/ exclamation marks, number of words is just the number of spaces in the text plus 1. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> //for the isalpha() function
#include <cs50.h>  //for the get_string() function

int main(void)
{
    int sentences = 0, letters = 0;
    int words = 1;
    char character;
    string text = get_string("Enter Text: \n");

    char x = 0;

    while (text[x] != '\0')
    {
        character = text[x];
        switch (character)
        {
        case ' ':
            words++;
            break;
        case '.':
            sentences++;
            break;
        case '?':
            sentences++;
            break;
        case '!':
            sentences++;
            break;
        default:
            if (isalpha(character))
            {
                letters++;
            }
        }
        x++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("WORDS: %d, LETTERS: %d, SENTENCES: %d\n", words, letters, sentences);
}
```

I'm fairly new to c, but I have around a year of experience in Python. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show the exact test input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: The code looks fine, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Please change `char x = 0;` to `int x = 0;` so it does not overflow on long lines.

Comment: Note you can use `isspace()` and `ispunct()` too.

Comment: I think `get_string` reads a single line up to CR, LF or CR+LF, so you have to call this function and the processing in a loop if you want to to read and process multiple lines of input. In this case you have to think about how the user should indicate the end of the input. Maybe an empty line or EOF? Check the return value of `get_string`. It will return a `NULL` pointer if an error was detected, e.g. if the input is longer than a maximum. In this case you must not try to access `text[x]`. Counting space characters to count words is only correct if every word is followed by exactly one space.

Comment: Start by adding `puts(text)` or `printf("%s\n", text);` just after `get_string`. Does the text print correctly?

Comment: Just because the terminal line overflows to / continues on the next line when it is full does not mean you have entered more then one "line".

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! i don't know how I put x as a character! Thank you!

Comment: `x` is an array index not a character.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to make a few suggestions.

First, don’t use `get_string`<sup>1</sup> (or `scanf`, or `fgets`).  For a filter program like this, you don’t actually need to *store* the input in order to process it; use `getchar` (or `fgetc`) to read one character at a time and loop based on that:

```
int c;  // getchar returns int, not char
...
puts( "Enter Text:" );
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
{
  // test c instead of text[x]
}
```

This approach will handle input of any length (such as if you redirect a file as your input), and it avoids the potential overflow issue Weather Vane identified in the comments.  The downside is that you’ll have to manually signal `EOF` from the console for interactive input (using either Ctrl-z or Ctrl-d depending on your platform).

You can collapse some of your tests in your `switch`, such as

```
case '.' :     // Each of these cases "falls through"
case '!' :     // to the following case.
case '?' :
  words++;     // the end of a sentence is also the end of a word
  sentences++;
  break;
```

You’ll want to add cases to handle newlines and tabs:

```
case ' ' :
case '\n' :
case '\t' :
  words++;
  break;
```

except you don’t want to bump the `words` counter for repeating whitespace characters, or if the previous non-whitespace character was a punctuation character.  So you’ll want an extra variable to track the class of the previously-read character:

```
enum {NONE, TEXT, PUNCT, WHITE} class = NONE;
...
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
{
  switch( c )
  {
    case ' ' :
    case '\n' :
    case '\t' :
      if ( class == TEXT )
        words++;
      class = WHITE;
      break;
    
    case '.' :
    case '!' :
    case '?' :
      if ( class == TEXT )  // Don’t bump the word counter
        words++;            // if the previous character was
                            // was whitespace or .! ?
      if ( class != PUNCT ) // Don’t bump the sentence counter
        sentences++;        // for repeating punctuation
      
      class = PUNCT;
      break;
      ...
  }
}
```

There will still be weird corner cases where this won’t give a completely accurate count, but should be good enough for most input.

You should be able to figure out the rest from there.

---

1. The CS50 string handling and I/O routines like `get_string` are pretty slick, but they ***grossly*** misrepresent how C actually does things.  The `string` typedef is especially egregious because what it aliases is *not a string*.  Just be aware these tools will not be available outside the CS50 curriculum, so don’t become too reliant on them.

Comment: Yes, i thought if using get_char() but the cs50 checking system requires me to do it  the assigment *exactly* the way they said it. THank you for your assistance!